# Solve $(y')^2=(y/c)^2-1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification

Can someone help me solve $(y')^2=(y/c)^2-1$?  WolframAlpha is giving me $\frac 12(c^2 e^{(x/c)-k}+e^{k-(x/c)})$.  One book I have is giving me $y=c\cdot \cosh(\frac {x+b}c)$ -- but that one won't work for the HW problem I'm solving because with the conditions $y(0)=y(D)=0$ it gives $y$ as identically $0$ -- so it must not be the most general form (though it does clearly solve this).  I'm also seeing elsewhere that the answer should be $y_0 + A\cosh(k(x-x_0))$, which would work for these boundary conditions, but I'm having trouble verifying that it actually solves this ODE.

I'm just not at all good at solving nonlinear ODEs.

Comment: $\cosh(x)=\dfrac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2}$

Comment: OK, but only one of those terms has a constant in front of it, so I can't just factor it out.

Comment: By the way, what is $c$? Is it a constant?

Comment: Yes, it's a constant.

Comment: Are you sure about the W|A solution you said? Because I'm getting a completely [different](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+%28f%27%28x%29%29^2%3D%28f%27%28x%29%2Fa%29^2-1) solution.

Comment: You typed it in wrong.  Only the LHS should have a derivative.

Comment: Oh sorry, my bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\dfrac{dy}{dx} = \sqrt{\left(\frac{y}{c}\right)^2-1} \implies \int{\dfrac{dy}{\sqrt{\left(\dfrac{y}{c}\right)^2-1}}} =\int1dx$$

we let $u=\dfrac{y}{c}$, so $du = \dfrac{dy}{c}$

$$c\int{\dfrac{du}{\sqrt{u^2-1}}} =x+k$$

With $k$ a constant. Now, we know this is a "classic" integral: arccosh

$$c\int{\dfrac{du}{\sqrt{u^2-1}}} =x+k \implies \cosh^{-1}u=\dfrac{x+k}{c}\implies u = \cosh\dfrac{x+k}{c} \implies$$

$$\dfrac{y}{c} = \cosh\dfrac{x+k}{c} \implies y = c\cosh\dfrac{x+k}{c} $$

Answer (score 0):

With $ y'(x) = \tan\phi $ substitution the equation reduces to $  y = c \sec(\phi) $ which is the standard  ODE of Catenary:

$$ y = c \cosh (x/c) \tag {1*} $$

$$ c \dfrac{dy}{dx} = \sqrt{y^2-c^2} $$ transpose, integrate

$$ x/c = \cosh^{-1}\frac{y}{c} + C_1 $$ Choosing symmetric BC, $ C_1$ can be made to vanish getting (1*).

Else, choosing general  BC:

$$ y = c \cosh ((x- C_2)/c) \tag {1*} $$

btw, it is sketched often with its involute, the Tractrix.

Answer (score 0):

### "Elementary" solution (The Sh. Holmes type "elementary")

From the form of the equation we see that it is a hyperbolic relation 
$$
1=(y/c)^2-(y')^2
$$
that can be parametrized as $y(x)/c=\cosh(u(x))$ and $y'(x)=\sinh(u(x))$. Consistency is reached when the derivative of the first coincides with the second, 
$$
\sinh(u(x))=y'(x)=c·\sinh(u(x))·u'(x)
$$
which gives $u'=1/c$ or $u(x)=x/c+k$. Thus
$$
y(x)=c·\cosh(x/c+k)
$$
for some $k\in\Bbb R$.

---

$y(0)=0$ is not possible in the real numbers since $(y')^2=-1$ is not solvable. However, $\cosh(\pm i\frac\pi2)=\cos(\pm \frac\pi2)=0$