# $ff'' - f '^2 = 1$ with $f$ a twice differentiable function, defined on $\mathbb R$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$ff''- f'^2=1$$ From that I showed that $f$ is different from zero on $\mathbb{R}$ and that $\frac{f''}{f}$ is constant on $\mathbb{R}$, so I have:
$$f'^2-\frac{f''}{f}\cdot f^2 = 1$$ 
and I don't know what to do next.

Comment: Hint: What is $(f'/f)'$?

Comment: See also the same problem: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2771858/115115, some part of the solution: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1206284/115115, also for context on the catenary: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2411419/115115

Answer (score 2):

One trick you can always try with autonomous second order equations is to assume that some reduction to a first order equation exists, $f'=u(f)$. Then $f''=u'(f)u(f)$ and the equation reads
$$
u'uf-u^2=1
$$
where it is more visible that the equation is separable,
$$
 \frac{u'u}{1+u^2}=\frac1f\implies 1+u^2=k^2f^2.
$$

---

With this as guide one can reverse engineer the transformations to get the same without the additional function,
$$
\frac{2f''f'}{1+f'^2}=\frac{2f'}f
$$
which again has easily integrable expressions on both sides.

Answer (score 1):

Write $f''/f=k^2$ so $f=f_0\cosh kx+k^{-1}f_0'\sinh kx$ and $$1=k^2f^2-f'^2=(k^2f_0^2-f_0'^2)(\cosh^2 kx-\sinh^2 kx)=k^2f_0^2-f_0'^2.$$This gives the parameterisation$$f_0=k^{-1}\cosh\theta,\,f_0'=\sin\theta\implies f=k^{-1}\cosh (kx+\theta).$$

Comment: thank you for your help, but what is $f0$ ?

Comment: @LutzL I was building on what the OP said they'd already done.

Answer (score 1):

$$ff''- f'^2=1$$
Susbstitute $$p=f' \implies f''=\frac {df'}{dx}=\frac {df'}{df}\frac {df}{dx}=p'p$$
$$fpp'-p^2=1$$
It's separable
$$\implies fpp'=1+p^2 \implies \int \frac {pdp}{1+p^2}=\int \frac {df}f$$

---

Here is another approach
$$ff''- f'^2=1$$
$$\implies (\frac {f'}f)'=\frac 1 {f^2}$$
$$d(\frac {f'}f)=\frac {dx} {f^2}$$
$$\frac {f'}fd(\frac {f'}f)=\frac {f'}f\frac {dx} {f^2}$$
$$\frac {f'}fd(\frac {f'}f)=\frac {df} {f^3}$$
$$\int \frac {f'}fd(\frac {f'}f)=\int \frac {df} {f^3}$$

---

You can also integrate it this way
$$fpp'-p^2=1$$

$$(p^2)'\frac f 2-p^2=1$$
Substitute $v=p^2$
$$v'-\frac 2fv=\frac 2f$$
This last DE is linear of first order